# Is there anyway to restrict c++ template class parameters within one-to-one relationship?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, sfinae

For example, there is a template class:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
class Example;
```

If a pair of (A, B) is specialized, then other types cannot specialized with A. For example, (B, C) is allowed, but (A, C) is not allowed.

```
Example<int, double> E1, E2, E3;  // OK
Example<int, double> E4;          // OK
Example<int, bool> E5;            // Not Allowed (Because <int, double> already exists)
Example<bool, double> E6;         // OK
Example<double, double> E7;       // OK
Example<double, int> E8;          // Not Allowed (<double, double> already exists)
```

I try to use a std::map between template parameter A and B during runtime, but if there is a way to do this during compiling? Like SFINAE or other techniques?

Comment: The problem with the very concept of this idea is that order of instantiation between compilation units is undefined\implementation-defined, and is local to that unit but instantiated entities are ODR-used. So any substitution, which would render another subsitution illegal, also would be in state of ODR-breach with compilation units other than one it had happened in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `friend` function definition that depends on `A` but not `B`.

```
template <typename> struct tag {};

template <typename A, typename B>
class Example
{
    friend constexpr void a_tag(tag<A>) {}
};
```

If you try to instantiate it with two different `B`s but the same `A`, you'll get a duplicate definition error for the function, as two different instantiations will try to define it.

Note that it only checks inside a single translation unit (as the function is implicitly `inline`). If you want the same test across the TUs, you need to additionally keep your runtime map.

Comment: Returning `tag<B>` might help linker to spot the issue across TUs.

Comment: @Jarod42 Nope, no luck. Tried returning `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, also nothing. Perhaps some linker flag is needed.

Answer (score 5):

The only real way I can think of is to *not* make it two template parameters, but instead one that provides a fixed mapping to the second type:

```
template <typename T>
struct ExampleAssociated { static_assert(false, "must specialize this"); };
template <typename A>
class Example {
  using B = typename ExampleAssociated<A>::type;
};

template <>
struct ExampleAssociated<int> { using type = double; };
template <>
struct ExampleAssociated<bool> { using type = double; };
// ...

Example<int> E1; // OK
Example<bool> E6; // OK
```